# Size limit on sending an email in Cloud Code via SendGrid

Tags: javascript, email, parse-platform, sendgrid

There appears to be an issue sending an large email through Parse cloud code using the SendGrid module. Certain messages wont send and return with a 400 error.

```
    {"Cache-Control":"no-cache","Connection":"close",
    "Content-Type":"text/html","Date":"Wed, 13 Aug 2014 03:21:13 GMT",
    "Server":"nginx/1.4.7"},"text":"<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
    \nYour browser sent an invalid request.\n</body></html>\n"
```

When I reduce the size of the html string I send, it works without any trouble. There's little to no documentation on Sendgrid for Parse.

Below is the code where I send the email. The html string I send is roughly 4300 characters.

```
    var hostEmail = host.attributes.user.attributes.email;
    var subject = visitorFullName + " is here to see you";
    var html = '@@html-email text goes here';

    SendGrid.sendEmail({
        to: hostEmail,
        from: "no-reply@example.co",
        subject: subject,
        html: html
    }, {
        success: function(httpResponse) {
             response.success('email sent');
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            response.error(httpResponse);
        }
    });
```

Is there any way to get this working with long strings? Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest opening this as a bug report on developers.facebook.com

Comment: Thanks for this. This is a bug and it has been resolved :) I will be handing this off to the administrators at Parse in for them to deploy it. I will comment on this again when it has been deployed. 

In the meantime, the most up to date source code can be found [here](https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-parse).

To use it, simply require it instead of the one in the Parse environment and everything should work :)

We are also working on making the docs more friendly!